# PHP Implode Value

Tags: php, implode

How can I get a single value from the array below? The current result for the 19th row is like 19 repeated twice as;

E:/database/users/**1919**/

I just need the 19, so the URL will look like;

E:/database/users/**19**/

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('C:/inetpub/wwwroot/database.db');
$row = $db->query('select id from users');
while ($lastrow = $row->fetchArray())
{
$id = implode($lastrow);
}
$database = 'E:/database/users/'.$id.'/';
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to create a URL for every single id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SQLite3Result::fetchArray`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php) by default uses the `SQLITE3_BOTH` mode, which returns a 0-indexed and associative array of the selected columns.

Meaning you will receive a value like:

```
$lastrow = array(
   0 => '19',
   'id' => '19'
);
```

To resolve the issue you simply need to change `fetchArray` to retrieve a single value using either `SQLITE3_NUM` or `SQLITE3_ASSOC`.

```
$row = $db->query('select id from users');
while ($lastrow = $row->fetchArray(SQLITE3_NUM)) {
    $id = implode($lastrow);
    //list($id) = $lastrow; //alternative to implode
}
$database = 'E:/database/users/'.$id.'/';
```

Alternatively you only need to specify the column name to retrieve, instead of using `implode`.

```
$row = $db->query('select id from users');
while ($lastrow = $row->fetchArray()) {
    $id = $lastrow['id'];
}
$database = 'E:/database/users/'.$id.'/';
```

---

Since it appears you only need the last row, I recommend changing your query to improve overall performance.

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM users
```

or

```
SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Allowing you to retrieve the last id without iterating over the entire users table.

```
if ($row = $db->query('SELECT MAX(id) FROM users')) {
    if ($row->numColumns()) {
        list($id) = $row->fetchArray(SQLITE3_NUM);
        $database = 'E:/database/users/'.$id.'/';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the value of `$lastrow` is array which is correct, and you said that it gets the value twice, you may try this, declare `$id = array()` and try to re assign value to `$id = array_shift($lastrow)` then another variable that will handle the value like `$implodedArray = implode($id)` and set to your like `$database = 'E:/database/users/'.$implodedArray .'/';` this should be getting the value `19`. This is an idea to manipulate your array.

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me. But had to set @fyrye as the answer. Thank you!